# How do I tell KiCad where the power is coming from on a Eeschema

Tags: power-supply, kicad, symbol, schematic, vcc

#### The problem

I am a beginner/novice using KiCad and in creating PCB's, so I do not know much about these things.  After following tutorials from YouTube I managed to create or copy symbols to my library and connect footprints to them.  But now, when I start connecting them in the schema I get a lot of errors.  I think most of them are because I am not telling KiCad where the power is comming from, even though I've added a Barrel Jack which has a power output on the VCC pin.

I am working on creating a PCB for my [WaterMixer](https://github.com/guttih/watermixer) project.

#### KiCad project files

The KiCad project files (including the project symbol and footprint libraries) are located in the [hardware](https://github.com/guttih/WaterMixer/tree/PCB/hardware/KiCad) directory on the branch I'm currently working on.

#### The Eeschema

Here is an image of my Eeschema which can be opened from the [hardware](https://github.com/guttih/WaterMixer/tree/PCB/hardware/KiCad) folder if anybody is interested.
[image: My current Schema]

#### The errors

Here are the errors generated by electrical rules checker (the debugger) if someone needs more information to answer the question.

```
ERC report (15.9.2021 09:44:30, Encoding UTF8 )

***** Sheet /
ErrType(3): Pin connected to other pins, but not driven by any pin
    @(220,98 mm, 142,24 mm): Pin 10 (Power input) of component U4 is not driven (Net 5).
ErrType(5): Conflict problem between pins. Severity: error
    @(121,92 mm, 125,73 mm): Pin 2 (Power output) of component U_5V1 is connected to 
    @(119,38 mm, 125,73 mm): pin 2 (Power output) of component U_5V1 (net 9).
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(133,35 mm, 179,07 mm): Pin 3 (Passive) of component J_12V1 is unconnected.
ErrType(3): Pin connected to other pins, but not driven by any pin
    @(172,72 mm, 74,93 mm): Pin 1 (Power input) of component U2 is not driven (Net 17).
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(199,39 mm, 116,84 mm): Pin 7 (Bidirectional) of component U3 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(199,39 mm, 93,98 mm): Pin 6 (Bidirectional) of component U3 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(204,47 mm, 116,84 mm): Pin 5 (Bidirectional) of component U3 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(204,47 mm, 93,98 mm): Pin 4 (Bidirectional) of component U3 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(172,72 mm, 57,15 mm): Pin 8 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(172,72 mm, 59,69 mm): Pin 7 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(172,72 mm, 62,23 mm): Pin 6 (Input) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(172,72 mm, 67,31 mm): Pin 4 (Input) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(172,72 mm, 34,29 mm): Pin 17 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(172,72 mm, 36,83 mm): Pin 16 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(172,72 mm, 44,45 mm): Pin 13 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(172,72 mm, 49,53 mm): Pin 11 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(172,72 mm, 52,07 mm): Pin 10 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(172,72 mm, 31,75 mm): Pin 18 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(236,22 mm, 134,62 mm): Pin 8 (Output) of component U4 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(205,74 mm, 137,16 mm): Pin 5 (Output) of component U4 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(205,74 mm, 134,62 mm): Pin 4 (Input) of component U4 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(102,87 mm, 49,53 mm): Pin 28 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(102,87 mm, 69,85 mm): Pin 36 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(102,87 mm, 67,31 mm): Pin 35 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(102,87 mm, 64,77 mm): Pin 34 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(172,72 mm, 69,85 mm): Pin 3 (Input) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(102,87 mm, 46,99 mm): Pin 27 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(102,87 mm, 41,91 mm): Pin 25 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(102,87 mm, 34,29 mm): Pin 22 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(102,87 mm, 31,75 mm): Pin 21 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(102,87 mm, 29,21 mm): Pin 20 (Bidirectional) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(172,72 mm, 72,39 mm): Pin 2 (Input) of component U2 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(76,20 mm, 74,93 mm): Pin 9 (Output) of component U1 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(35,56 mm, 85,09 mm): Pin 18 (Input) of component U1 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(121,92 mm, 146,05 mm): Pin 1 (Power input) of component U_5V1 is unconnected.
ErrType(3): Pin connected to other pins, but not driven by any pin
    @(55,88 mm, 90,17 mm): Pin 2 (Power input) of component U1 is not driven (Net 64).
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(110,49 mm, 146,05 mm): Pin 3 (Passive) of component U_5V1 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(113,03 mm, 146,05 mm): Pin 3 (Passive) of component U_5V1 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(119,38 mm, 146,05 mm): Pin 1 (Power input) of component U_5V1 is unconnected.
ErrType(5): Conflict problem between pins. Severity: error
    @(67,31 mm, 118,11 mm): Pin 2 (Power output) of component U_3.3V1 is connected to 
    @(64,77 mm, 118,11 mm): pin 2 (Power output) of component U_3.3V1 (net 68).
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(55,88 mm, 138,43 mm): Pin 3 (Passive) of component U_3.3V1 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(58,42 mm, 138,43 mm): Pin 3 (Passive) of component U_3.3V1 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(64,77 mm, 138,43 mm): Pin 1 (Power input) of component U_3.3V1 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(67,31 mm, 138,43 mm): Pin 1 (Power input) of component U_3.3V1 is unconnected.

 ** ERC messages: 44  Errors 2  Warnings 42
```

### Update Fix 1

After suggestion from "Andy aka" I've Added a PWR_FLAG and marked pins not used.  This Fixed a lot of errors.  But now I'm not sure how to fix the rest.  I'm adding a new Image to show what I did and also adding the image of the two symbols I suspect having the wrong pin types.

#### Images of the new (Fix1) Schema and the symbols

##### the Schema after Fix1

The Schema after fixing it with "Andy aka" suggestions.

[image]

##### Symbols

I suspect that the pin types could be wrong on these symbols.

##### Symbol Barrel_Jack

The 12V power plug.

[image: Barrel_Jack Symbol]

##### Symbol SD_BUCK3A

The power step down voltage module to produce 3.3V and 5V power.
[image: Buck]

#### The errors after Fix 1

```
ERC report (15.9.2021 12:32:00, Encoding UTF8 )

***** Sheet /
ErrType(3): Pin connected to other pins, but not driven by any pin
    @(214,63 mm, 102,87 mm): Pin 1 (Power input) of component U3 is not driven (Net 5).
ErrType(5): Conflict problem between pins. Severity: error
    @(121,92 mm, 125,73 mm): Pin 2 (Power output) of component U_5V1 is connected to 
    @(119,38 mm, 125,73 mm): pin 2 (Power output) of component U_5V1 (net 9).
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(151,13 mm, 185,42 mm): Pin 1 (Power output) of component #FLG02 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(151,13 mm, 166,37 mm): Pin 1 (Power output) of component #FLG01 is unconnected.
ErrType(12): Different net assigned to a shared pin in another unit of the same component
    @(64,77 mm, 138,43 mm): Pin 1 on U_3.3V1 is connected to both VCC and Net-(U_3.3V1-Pad1)
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(133,35 mm, 176,53 mm): Pin 2 (Passive) of component J_12V1 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(121,92 mm, 146,05 mm): Pin 1 (Power input) of component U_5V1 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(236,22 mm, 134,62 mm): Pin 8 (Output) of component U4 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(205,74 mm, 137,16 mm): Pin 5 (Output) of component U4 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(205,74 mm, 134,62 mm): Pin 4 (Input) of component U4 is unconnected.
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(119,38 mm, 146,05 mm): Pin 1 (Power input) of component U_5V1 is unconnected.
ErrType(12): Different net assigned to a shared pin in another unit of the same component
    @(58,42 mm, 138,43 mm): Pin 3 on U_3.3V1 is connected to both Net-(U_3.3V1-Pad3) and GND
ErrType(3): Pin connected to other pins, but not driven by any pin
    @(102,87 mm, 59,69 mm): Pin 32 (Power input) of component U2 is not driven (Net 61).
ErrType(5): Conflict problem between pins. Severity: error
    @(64,77 mm, 118,11 mm): Pin 2 (Power output) of component U_3.3V1 is connected to 
    @(67,31 mm, 118,11 mm): pin 2 (Power output) of component U_3.3V1 (net 66).
ErrType(12): Different net assigned to a shared pin in another unit of the same component
    @(113,03 mm, 146,05 mm): Pin 3 on U_5V1 is connected to both GND and Net-(U_5V1-Pad3)
ErrType(2): Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
    @(76,20 mm, 74,93 mm): Pin 9 (Output) of component U1 is unconnected.

 ** ERC messages: 16  Errors 5  Warnings 11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ErrType(3): Pin connected to other pins, but not driven by any pin
```

Connect a power flag symbol to power lines to inform KiCad: -

[image]

```
Pin not connected (use a “no connection” flag to suppress this error)
```

And use a no-connect symbol on pins that are unused: -

[image]

That should sort out most of them.

I would also recommend that you use symbols for Vcc and GND rather than traipse them across the schematic. You might need a few more de-coupling capacitors too on Vcc/Vdd pins to ground.

Comment: I will follow your instruction this evening (after work).  Thank you for the information :)

Comment: @GuðjónHólmSigurðsson don't forget to come back tomorrow!

Comment: thanks for your input.  I stole a little time from work to apply your fixes as best I could.  I added the results to the original post (edited) starting from "Update Fix 1".    There are still some errors I'm not sure how to fix, could you help a little with that?

Comment: Thanks @andyaka (testing how to refer to users in comments)

Comment: @guttih yes, your test worked!. The remaining errors appear to be power pin conflicts but you still have some pins that can be fixed with the blue X as indicated in my answer.  For your power pin conflicts, I normally set all relevant pins to be passive so that the conflict disappears. [Please read this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why people give help for free.

Comment: Note that the blue cross attaches at the free end of the pin and not how you attached on U_3.3V1. Also edit your symbols to rotate pins 4 and 2 so that they point outwards from the chip.

Comment: Thank you for all your help @andyaka, I'm error free, wohooo :)